# Elasticsearch filtering with nested query inner_hits count

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query:

```
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "cuccok",
            "inner_hits": {},
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "cuccok.point": [
                                    1,
                                    2
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "cuccok.tag": [
                                    3,
                                    4
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 2,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "cucc",
                "_id": "IkREdogBdZE48qyFJ4QS",
                "_score": 2,
                "_source": {
                    "itemid": 1,
                    "cuccok": [
                        {
                            "point": 1,
                            "tag": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "point": 2,
                            "tag": 4
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inner_hits": {
                    "cuccok": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 2,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "cucc",
                                    "_id": "IkREdogBdZE48qyFJ4QS",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "cuccok",
                                        "offset": 0
                                    },
                                    "_score": 2,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "point": 1,
                                        "tag": 3
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_index": "cucc",
                                    "_id": "IkREdogBdZE48qyFJ4QS",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "cuccok",
                                        "offset": 1
                                    },
                                    "_score": 2,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "point": 2,
                                        "tag": 4
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "cucc",
                "_id": "I0REdogBdZE48qyFJ4Qf",
                "_score": 2,
                "_source": {
                    "itemid": 2,
                    "cuccok": [
                        {
                            "point": 1,
                            "tag": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "point": 2,
                            "tag": 5
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inner_hits": {
                    "cuccok": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 1,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 2,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "cucc",
                                    "_id": "I0REdogBdZE48qyFJ4Qf",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "cuccok",
                                        "offset": 0
                                    },
                                    "_score": 2,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "point": 1,
                                        "tag": 3
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'd like to return only the first (itemid = 1) doc, where the nested query inner_hits count = 2 (highlighted with bold in the result).

How can I implement this?